# ADL and container functions (begin, end, etc)

Tags: c++

C++11 and later define free functions `begin`, `end`, `empty`, etc in namespace std. For most containers these functions invoke the corresponding member function. But for some containers (like `valarray`) these free functions are overloaded (initializer_list does not have a member begin()). So to iterate over any container free functions should be used and to find functions for container from namespaces other than `std` ADL should be used:

```
 template<typename C>
 void foo(C c)
 {
   using std::begin;
   using std::end;
   using std::empty;

   if (empty(c)) throw empty_container();
   for (auto i = begin(c); i != end(c); ++i) { /* do something */ }
 }
```

**Question 1**: Am I correct? Are `begin` and `end` expected to be found via ADL?

But ADL rules specify that if type of an argument is a class template specialization ADL includes namespaces of all template arguments. And then Boost.Range library comes into play, it defines `boost::begin`, `boost::end`, etc.  These functions are defined like this:

```
template< class T >
inline BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME range_iterator<T>::type begin( T& r )
{
    return range_begin( r );
}
```

If I use `std::vector<boost::any>` and a Boost.Range I run into trouble. std::begin and boost::begin overloads are ambiguous. That it, I can not write template code that will find a free `begin` via ADL. If I explicitly use `std::begin` I expect that any non-`std::` container has a member `begin`.

**Question 2**: What shall I do in this case?

*Rely on the presence of member function?* Simplest way.

*Ban Boost.Range?* Well, algorithms that take container instead of a pair of iterators are convinient. Boost.Range adaptors (containers that lazily apply an algorithm to a container) are also convinient. But if I do not use Boost.Range in my code it still can be used in a boost library (other than Range). This make template code really fragile.

*Ban Boost?*

Comment: `initializer_list` does have member functions `begin`, `end` o.O -- in C++11 and still today.

Comment: maybe c-style array would be a better example

Comment: But `initializer_list` still does not have an `empty` or `size` member functions. Consider a function that checks if a container is not empty.

Comment: Related: http://wg21.link/n3257

Comment: It has member `size` too. [RTFM](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few years ago, I had a similar problem where my code suddenly started getting ambiguities between `std::begin` and `boost::begin`.  I found it was due to using [Boost.Operator](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/utility/operators.htm) to aid in defining a class, even though it was not even a public base class or apparent to the user of the types involved.  A random change somewhere caused `#include <boost/range/begin.hpp>` to be present in the nested include files somewhere, thus making `boost::begin` visible to the compiler.

I complained to the mailing list about the putting of classes directly in the Boost namespace, rather than in a nested class and exposing them via `using` declarations; all stuff defined directly in the Boost namespace *could* potentially step on each other via accidental ADL.

I just tried to reproduce this today, and it seems quite resilient against such ambiguities now!  Looking at the definition, `boost::begin` is itself in an inner namespace so it can *never* be found via unqualified lookup if you had not supplied your own `using boost::begin;` in your own scope.

I don’t know how long ago this fix took place.  (If you can still reproduce it, please post a complete program with version and platform details.)

## So your answer is:

For Boost, don’t worry about it anymore (upgrade Boost if necessary).

For new code, never define a free function named `begin` in the same namespace as any of its defined types.